# File Does Not Exist - Drupal Migrate module

Tags: files, migrations

I am using the Migrate Drupal UI module to upgrade a simple Drupal 7 site to Drupal 9 using the web browser upgrade form.

I am having an issue where when the upgrade runs it says the files do not exist.

Here is what I have tried:

Run the upgrade through the form with correct database credentials and with the source path sites/default/files and this is what the error looks like
SOURCE ID 6017: d7_file:uri:file_copy: File 'sites/default/files/folder-name/file-name.zip' does not exist

Before running the upgrade, manually put the files in the sites/default/files folder on the blank drupal 9 site using FTP, run it and this is what the error looks like.
SOURCE ID 6017: d7_file:uri:file_copy: File 'sites/default/files//folder-name/file-name.zip' does not exist

Some other important info: -the file types are zip files -note with the second attempt a double slash appears in front of the folder

Comment: Can you check if the folder and file actually exist on your server? The migration script finds the filename "sites/default/files//folder-name/file-name.zip" in the rupal 7 database and uses to to try to copy the actual file. This error occurs because the file cannot be found while trying to copy the file.

Comment: I don’t think you are supposed to move the files yourself in advance of the migration.